# Как лучше сделать срез элемента целого числа?

Tags: python, python-3.x, числа

Как лучше сделать срез элемента целого числа?
И как при помощи for перебрать целое число по цифрам, учитывая что числа не итерируемые объекты?
Можно сначала преобразовать в строку или список. А есть еще какие-нибудь способы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Преобразовать целое число в строку, сделать срез. Если необходимо, преобразовать срез обратно в целое число.
2. В цикле делить число на 10, остаток от деления заносить в список. По окончании цикла расположить числа в списке в обратном порядке (например, с помощью встроенного метода списков reverse()).

Comment: Невероятно! Спасибо! Сам бы не понял насчет деления на 10.